# Can't import requests_oauthlib

Tags: python, macos, oauth

I've failed to import `requests_oauthlib`, although I've installed it successfully:

```
$ sudo pip install requests requests_oauthlib
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-oauthlib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
~ alex$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests_oauthlib
```

update:

```
>>> import sys; print sys.path
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the results from running this in python: `import sys; print sys.path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requests-oauthlib` is installed at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

But the latter is not in your PYTHONPATH/sys.path

So add it.  This is one way.

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```

[Learn about pythonpath](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: by the way, why do you think it's not in my PYTHONPAHT, the output says it is `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests-oauthlib in usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd guess that `pip` looks in that directory via some default setting, but your application never looks anywhere but the directories specified by the pythonpath.

Answer (score 18):

I had this issue and in addition to making sure the correct path was set, I found that running 
`$ pip install requests requests_oauthlib` 
solved the issue, as oauthlib is not included in the core `requests` library.

https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib

Comment: When running that I got `ImportError: No module named _internal`